# Create a record where the Model inherits from another Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How do I set a models reference property correctly?

I have a Model called Platform which has a navigational property to a model called Service.

The issue I am having is with setting the value of platformToCreate.Service.

Here is a screenshot of the Platform table:

[alt text http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/6394/platform.jpg](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/6394/platform.jpg)

Here is a screenshot of the EDM:

[alt text http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/3664/edms.jpg](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/3664/edms.jpg)

Code:

```
[ValidateInput(true)]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "id")] Platform platformToCreate)
        {

            ViewData["title"] = platformToCreate.title;
            ViewData["url"] = platformToCreate.url;
            ViewData["platform_nm"] = platformToCreate.platform_nm;
            ViewData["enabled"] = platformToCreate.enabled;

            int selectedService = int.Parse(Request.Form["service_id"].ToString());

            var cats = from c in db.Services select c;
            ViewData["service_id"] = new SelectList(cats, "id", "name", selectedService);

            if (!_service.CreatePlatform(platformToCreate))
                return View(platformToCreate);

            TempData["Msg"] = "Record Created";
            return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Home" });
        }
```

Comment: Hi Nick, can you give me more detail about what you are trying to do? Your goal isn't clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: Jeremy - i need to add a record into table Platforms. Normally I would run a proc which inserts the record with the selected service_id. Using this framework, I can add a record but service_id is not part of that classes members. Services is. So how do I specify the service related to the new record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what version of EF you are using and even if I knew what version the possibilities are still endless. :) I'll give you a few examples.

Version 1.0

```
public void Update(User user)
{

    using (var context = new ObjectContext(""))
    {
        user.Blog = GetBlog(user.Id);

        context.ApplyPropertyChanges("User", user);
    }
}

private Blog GetBlog(int userId)
{
    using (var context = new ObjectContext(""))
    {
        return (from u in context.Users
                where u.Id == userId
                select u).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

In version 2 and POCO:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }

    public void AddEntry(Entry entry)
    {
        if (Blog.Entries == null)
            Blog.Entries = new List<Entry>();

        entry.Blog = Blog;
        Blog.Entries.Add(entry);
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
}
```

Then of course there are a multitude of options using the EntityKey values, loading references etc. I tend to use the easiest variant at hand though.

**EDIT:** Ok got your question. MVC is very forgiving if you treat it right. I would start with the following: When you create your select list thats fine:

```
ViewData["service_id"] = new SelectList(cats, "id", "name", selectedService);
```

But to use this select list correctly in MVC you can actually assign it like the following:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Service.Id", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["service_id"])%>
```

The thing to note here is **Service.Id**. This means that whatever value is selected in the drop down list get's assigned to Platform.Service.Id. When you persist your changes Entity Framework does the work for you.

Comment: i tried version 1 of your code but it is throwing an error: The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type 'Admin.Models.Platform'.